# Do classical waves have reflectionless potentials?

Tags: waves, scattering, string

In quantum mechanics, there exist [reflectionless potentials](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/246843/reflectionless-potentials-in-quantum-mechanics), i.e. potentials whose transmission coefficient is one regardless of the incoming energy.

For a classical wave, such as a wave on a string, one could imagine creating a 'potential' by adding a term to the wave equation,
$$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2} = v^2 \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial^2 x} + k(x)y.$$
Physically, this would correspond to attaching the string to vertical springs with strength proportional to $k(x)$. Do there exist reflectionless potentials for this problem?

Comment: The closest I can think of is noise cancellation but I don't think that's the same.